# How to switch on/off LED "flood illuminator" on iPhone with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How do I switch on/off the LED "flood illuminator" on an iPhone with Xcode? I made a program using BiometricKit.framework but it doesn't work, the flood illuminator only opens when I set up Face ID.

I'm using the following code:

```
Class BKDeviceManager = NSClassFromString(@"BKDeviceManager");
NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[BKDeviceManager availableDevices];
NSLog(@"manager availableDevices: %@", array);
            
Class BKDeviceDescriptor = NSClassFromString(@"BKDeviceDescriptor");
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    id descriptor = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"object: %@", descriptor);
}
if (array.count < 1)
    return;
id descriptor = [array objectAtIndex:0];
//Class BKDevice = NSClassFromString(@"BKDevice");
NSError *err = nil;
BKDevice *device = [BKDevice deviceWithDescriptor:descriptor error:&err];
NSLog(@"err: %@", err);
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"err: %@", [err description]);
    return;
}
                       
NSLog(@"BKFaceDetectOperation: %@", NSClassFromString(@"BKFaceDetectOperation"));
Class BKFaceDetectOperation = NSClassFromString(@"BKFaceDetectOperation");
id object = [[BKFaceDetectOperation alloc] initWithDevice:device];
NSLog(@"object: %@ start Bio Operation", object);
[object startBioOperation:YES reply: ^{
     NSLog(@"This is a block startBioOperation reply run action");
}];
```

Comment: You sure you mean the "Flood illuminator" at the front of the device? Thats not possible.

Comment: it is a square led located on the top, to the left of the device, near to the proximity led

Comment: I'm using Portrait camera front but "Flood illuminator" not open, only open "Proximity led" and "Dot Projector".